# Update shapefile with values from Excel cell in QGIS

Tags: qgis, excel

I have an Excel table with unique  Id values.

```
1
2
3
4
```

What I want to achieve is when editing a  point shapefile with the same Id field every time a new point is created the Id field is filled by the ids from the Excel table. 
The values in the table are quite unique and have aspecific structure so I cannot use the automatic id build tools within QGIS

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you tell us where you are stuck?

Comment: The real issue is that I am using an empty shapefile that is going to get records on the field with an external app. So I am stuck in the process when making new point record to have the id from the excel

Comment: Does it have to be dynamic like you describe? Or could all the values be added to the file *once*?

Comment: It has to be dynamic

Comment: By convention, the `ID` field is the zero-based record number in the shapefile. It is a pseudocolumn that always exists, and cannot be modified. You could certainly create a `myid` field and populate it however you like, but that will probably require coding. What have you written so far?

Comment: I have tried a combination of get_feature with an attribute but with no results. The expression is ok but it does not populate the shapefile.

Comment: Unclear on what you mean: "every time a new point is created the Id field is filled by the ids from the Excel table". Do you mean that for every new point you want to fill an integer attribute for the point using only the list of IDs from the Excel? Or do you want to look up other values in the Excel file and fill in the attribute table from them?

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your Excel table as .csv, load it into QGIS and establish a new connection in the Properties tab of your shapefile, using ID as a joining field...